# Connect geom_segment to geom_point outside the plot in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I need help to connect a geom_segment to a geom_point outside the plot. I tried looking up answers to similar questions but that did not solve my problem.

I have a plot with two y-axes as shown below:

[image]

I need to add an orange point at (15, 120). As you can see, each orange dot is connected with an orange geom_segment. However, geom_segment cannot draw outside the plot. I tried adding `coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 120), xlim = c(0,25), clip="off")` but that did not help. Maybe it has something to do with the double-y-axis?

My script is the following and `My data` can be found below.

```
j <-  ggplot() + theme_classic() +
  geom_bar(mapping = aes(x = w$ki67pro[w$recurrence==1]), stat = "count", alpha=0.2, colour="#51BFC4", fill="#51BFC4")

yaks <- c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
j <- j %+% scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0,0), name = "XX", breaks=yaks, sec.axis = sec_axis(~ . * 1 , name = "YY", breaks=yaks, labels=c("0.000","0.025","0.050","0.075","0.100","0.125","0.150", "0.175","0.200", "0.225")), limits = c(0, 8.5))

j + 
  geom_point(mapping = aes(x = 0, y = 2.008368), size=2.5, shape=16, colour="#F0746B") +
  geom_point(mapping = aes(x = 1, y = 0.0000000), size=2.5, shape=16, colour="#F0746B") +
  geom_point(mapping = aes(x = 2, y = 1.0706320), size=2.5, shape=16, colour="#F0746B") +
  geom_point(mapping = aes(x = 3, y = 0.8202982), size=2.5, shape=16, colour="#F0746B") +
  geom_point(mapping = aes(x = 4, y = 1.1170213), size=2.5, shape=16, colour="#F0746B") +
  geom_point(mapping = aes(x = 5, y = 2.1384815), size=2.5, shape=16, colour="#F0746B") +
  geom_point(mapping = aes(x = 6, y = 0.0000000), size=2.5, shape=16, colour="#F0746B") +
  geom_point(mapping = aes(x = 7, y = 3.6090226), size=2.5, shape=16, colour="#F0746B") +
  geom_point(mapping = aes(x = 8, y = 6.6666667), size=2.5, shape=16, colour="#F0746B") +
  geom_point(mapping = aes(x = 10, y = 3.0868167), size=2.5, shape=16, colour="#F0746B") +
  geom_point(mapping = aes(x = 12, y = 1.5604681), size=2.5, shape=16, colour="#F0746B") +
  geom_point(mapping = aes(x = 15, y = 120.0000000), size=2.5, shape=16, colour="#F0746B") +
  geom_point(mapping = aes(x = 20, y = 8.0672269), size=2.5, shape=16, colour="#F0746B") +
  geom_point(mapping = aes(x = 25, y = 0.0000000), size=2.5, shape=16, colour="#F0746B") +

  geom_segment(mapping = aes(x = 0, y = 2.008368, xend = 1, yend = 0), colour="#F0746B", alpha=1) +
  geom_segment(mapping = aes(x = 1, y = 0, xend = 2, yend = 1.0706320), colour="#F0746B", alpha=1) +
  geom_segment(mapping = aes(x = 2, y = 1.0706320, xend = 3, yend = 0.8202982), colour="#F0746B", alpha=1) +
  geom_segment(mapping = aes(x = 3, y = 0.8202982, xend = 4, yend = 1.1170213), colour="#F0746B", alpha=1) +
  geom_segment(mapping = aes(x = 4, y = 1.1170213, xend = 5, yend = 2.1384815), colour="#F0746B", alpha=1) +
  geom_segment(mapping = aes(x = 5, y = 2.1384815, xend = 6, yend = 0.0000000), colour="#F0746B", alpha=1) +
  geom_segment(mapping = aes(x = 6, y = 0, xend = 7, yend = 3.6090226), colour="#F0746B", alpha=1) +
  geom_segment(mapping = aes(x = 7, y = 3.6090226, xend = 8, yend = 6.6666667), colour="#F0746B", alpha=1) +
  geom_segment(mapping = aes(x = 8, y = 6.6666667, xend = 10, yend = 3.0868167), colour="#F0746B", alpha=1) +
  geom_segment(mapping = aes(x = 10, y = 3.0868167, xend = 12, yend = 1.5604681), colour="#F0746B", alpha=1) +
  geom_segment(mapping = aes(x = 12, y = 1.5604681, xend = 15, yend = 120), colour="#F0746B", alpha=1) +
  geom_segment(mapping = aes(x = 15, y = 120, xend = 20, yend = 8.0672269), colour="#F0746B", alpha=1) +
  geom_segment(mapping = aes(x = 20, y = 8.0672269, xend = 25, yend = 0), colour="#F0746B", alpha=1)  




My data
w <- structure(list(recurrence = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), ki67pro = c(1L, 12L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 
3L, 20L, 25L, 7L, 4L, 5L, 12L, 3L, 15L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 8L, 3L, 12L, 
10L, 4L, 10L, 7L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 7L, 4L, 7L, 10L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 
5L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 20L, 5L, 0L, 4L, 3L, 0L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 
20L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 8L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 6L, 12L, 3L, 4L, 
4L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
4L, 7L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 6L, 2L, 3L, 10L, 5L, 10L, 3L, 10L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 12L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 
2L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 6L, 1L, 4L, 12L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 6L, 
5L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 0L, 
3L)), .Names = c("recurrence", "ki67pro"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 
21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 
34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 
49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 57L, 59L, 60L, 61L, 62L, 63L, 
64L, 65L, 66L, 67L, 68L, 69L, 70L, 71L, 72L, 73L, 74L, 75L, 76L, 
77L, 78L, 79L, 80L, 81L, 82L, 83L, 84L, 85L, 87L, 89L, 90L, 91L, 
92L, 93L, 94L, 96L, 97L, 98L, 99L, 100L, 101L, 102L, 103L, 104L, 
105L, 106L, 107L, 109L, 110L, 111L, 112L, 113L, 114L, 115L, 116L, 
117L, 118L, 119L, 120L, 121L, 123L, 124L, 125L, 126L, 127L, 128L, 
130L, 131L, 132L, 133L, 134L, 135L, 136L, 137L, 138L, 139L, 140L, 
141L, 142L, 143L, 144L, 145L, 146L, 147L, 148L, 149L, 150L, 151L, 
152L, 153L, 154L, 155L, 156L, 157L, 158L, 159L, 160L, 161L, 162L, 
163L, 164L, 165L, 166L, 167L, 168L, 169L, 170L, 171L, 172L, 173L, 
174L, 175L))
```

Comment: Sorry I'm not answering your question directly, but thought this tip may be of use to you. Instead of having a `geom_point()` or `geom_segment()` line for every point/segment, you can put your variables in a data.frame where columns correspond to your mapping variables and plot all your points/segments at once by referring to the column names inside the `aes()` mapping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't set the limits with `scale_*()`.  Set it with `coord_*()`.

The first function (family) removes rows; the second functions zooms the perspective.

*edit*: This follows @teunbrand's comment.  Replace the fourth line with

```r
j <- j %+% 
  scale_y_continuous(
    expand=c(0,0), 
    name = "XX", 
    breaks=yaks, 
    # limits = c(0, 8.5), # This is the undesirable specification
    sec.axis = sec_axis(~ . * 1 , name = "YY", breaks=yaks, labels=c("0.000","0.025","0.050","0.075","0.100","0.125","0.150", "0.175","0.200", "0.225"))
  ) + 
  coord_cartesian(ylim=c(0, 8.5))
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I believe I tried that. Can you write out the line based on the script I uploaded?

Comment: Add `j + coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 8.5))`; remove the `limits = c(0, 8.5)` inside the `scale_y_continuous()` function.

Comment: I spelled it out, following @teunbrand's comment.  Stepping back a minute, consider avoiding all these hard coded commands, and [use a second dataset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36227233/plot-multiple-datasets-with-ggplot).